# Convert Matlab disparity image from single precision to uint8

Tags: matlab, disparity-mapping

I need to save the disparity image to my disk. The data type of the disparity image is single precision and the disparity range is [0 128].
While using `imwrite(disparityMap,file_name)`, the saved image appears to be binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use imwrite with floating point precision, matlab consider that your data is in the range [0 1]. So any value above 1 will be considered as 1. That is why you have a black and white image.

From [matlab doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) :

> If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values.

Then, you have two solution. I'm considering that 128 is the maximum in your data, and that you want a colormap that goes from black to white. I will

**First solution, normalize your data so that matlab do the right conversion:**

```
% Normalize your data between 0 and 1
disparityMap = disparityMap/128;

% write the image
imwrite(disparityMap,file_name)
```

**Second solution, do the conversion yourself and write the image directly as uint8:**

```
% Normalize your data between 0 and 255 and convert to uint8
disparityMapU8 = uint8(disparityMap*255/128);

% write the image as uint8
imwrite(disparityMapU8,file_name)
```